# Loading MKMapView inside a XIB throws 'key value coding-compliant' error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, mapkit, xib

Goal: Trying to reuse a UIView in my ViewController for different xib files. One xib has a MKMapView IBOutlet and the other xib has a cameraView(not included in the code below).

Problem: Swapping the XIB files without having any IBOutlets works fine but when I add an IBOutlet for MKMapView in one of the xib files, it throws this error:

"reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key map"

xib file:

MapView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface MapView : UIView <MKMapViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *map;
@end
```

MapView.m

```
#import "MapView.h"
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@implementation MapView 

-(id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
     if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])
{

    [self load];
 }
return self;
}

-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame])
    {
      [self load];
 }
return self;
}

-(void)load
{
    UIView *view = [[[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]]       loadNibNamed:@"MapView" owner:self options:nil] firstObject];
    [self addSubview:view];
    view.frame = self.bounds;
}

@end
```

ViewController:

DashboardViewController:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface DasboardViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate>

@end
```

DashboardViewController.m:

```
#import "DasboardViewController.h"
#import "MapView.h"
@interface DasboardViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *viewMain;
@property(nonatomic, strong) MapView *mapNib;
@end

@implementation DasboardViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _mapNib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MapView"   owner:self options:nil].firstObject;
    [_mapNib setFrame:_viewMain.bounds];
    [_mapNib setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |   UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
    [_viewMain addSubview:_mapNib];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: check in XIB for unmapped iboutlet or action ?

Comment: nope there are none.. i tried all other solutions for this error and nothing worked i even created a new application without copying any UI elements or code to replicate this error and it persisted. I strongly feel there is something wrong with my code. Especially in my Dashboard ViewController.. the way I am assigning the xib to the uiview programmatically... I also haven't linked the UIView 'viewMain' class to 'MapView'